# Uso de Jquery First y Clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<p>primer estudiante: <span id="primer_estudiante"></span></p>
<p>primer profesor: <span id="primer_profesor"></span></p>
<p>primer egresado: <span id="primer_egresado"></span></p>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">


    <div class="col-3" id="estudiantes">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">JUAN</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">MARIA</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">LUIS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-3" id="profesores">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">LOPEZ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">DIAZ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">BUSTOS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-3" id="egresados">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">ANDRES</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">LAURA</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">ANA</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>


</div>
```

Lo que quiero es que con javascript, sea vanilla o jquery, se complete en la parte superior (dentro de los `<span>`) con los valores del primer resultado de cada columna.

Lamentablemente no se como seleccionarlos cuando los elementos tienen la misma estructura, supongo que los id me pueden ayudar para diferenciar cada columna, con CSS sería algo así

```
#estudiantes > p.nombre {
/* estilos */
}

$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#estudiantes > p.nombre:first").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que quieres algo así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#primer_estudiante").html($("#estudiantes .nombre").html())
  $("#primer_profesor").html($("#profesores .nombre").html())
  $("#primer_egresado").html($("#egresados .nombre").html())
});
```

donde lo que hacemos es leer el contenido HTML que hay en el primer elemento con la clase `.nombre` que encuentra en cada div:

```
$("#estudiantes .nombre").html()
```

y lo asignamos al contenido de su correspondiente `span`:

```
  $("#primer_estudiante").html($("#estudiantes .nombre").html())
```

Ejemplo completo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#primer_estudiante").html($("#estudiantes .nombre").html())
  $("#primer_profesor").html($("#profesores .nombre").html())
  $("#primer_egresado").html($("#egresados .nombre").html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<p>primer estudiante: <span id="primer_estudiante"></span></p>
<p>primer profesor: <span id="primer_profesor"></span></p>
<p>primer egresado: <span id="primer_egresado"></span></p>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-3" id="estudiantes">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">JUAN</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">MARIA</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">LUIS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3" id="profesores">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">LOPEZ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">DIAZ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">BUSTOS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3" id="egresados">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">ANDRES</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">LAURA</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="nombre">ANA</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No conocia esa fomrma de hacerlo, muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiemmpo